# Show that $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+1+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1+1)!}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> In an induction step I have to show that $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+1+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(n+1+1)!}$ ? I've tried manipulating the terms but didn't get them to fit. It may be possible that they do not match but its unlikely given the original task.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{n+1}{(n+1+1)!}-\dfrac1{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{n+1-(n+1+1)}{(n+1+1)!}=-\dfrac1{(n+1+1)!}$$

Comment: yup looks good, thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

Writing $(n+1+1)!$ as $(n+2)!$ we can rewrite the left hand side to be:

$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$ Mutliplying the first two terms by $\frac{n+2}{n+2}$ we get the left hand side as:

$\frac{n+2}{n+2}-\frac{n+2}{(n+2)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$ and then we take a factor of $\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$ out of each term to give the left hand side as:

$\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\large[(n+2)! - (n+2) +(n+1)\large]$. Simplifying the square brackets gives the left hand side as:

$\frac{(n+2)!-1}{(n+2)!}$ and we can break this up to give $1-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$ which is our right hand side. The crucial thing here is that $(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$